# Objective-C setter is never called

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, setter, getter

I'm trying to make an NSMutableArray usable in multiple classes.  I'm having an issue with defining and using a custom setter, for some reason, even though I call my setter, it is never executed (I have an NSLog set up in the method).  Here is all of the relevant code:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface TouchTrackerAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

NSMutableArray *completeLines;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain, setter = setCompleteLines:, getter = getCompleteLines) NSMutableArray *completeLines;


-(NSMutableArray*) getCompleteLines;
-(void) setCompleteLines:(NSMutableArray *) newLines;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation TouchTrackerAppDelegate

-(NSMutableArray*) getCompleteLines {
return self.completeLines;
}

-(void) setCompleteLines:(NSMutableArray *)newLines {
NSLog(@"gets here");
if (completeLines != newLines) {
    [completeLines release];
    completeLines = [newLines retain];
}

NSLog(@"completeLines global count: %i",[completeLines count]);
}
```

**View.h**

```
#import "TouchTrackerAppDelegate.h"

@interface TouchDrawView : UIView {
NSMutableDictionary     *linesInProcess;
NSMutableArray          *completeLines;
TouchTrackerAppDelegate *navigationDelegate;
}
@end
```

**View.m***

```
#import "TouchTrackerAppDelegate.h"

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)c 
{
[super initWithCoder:c];
linesInProcess = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
completeLines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
navigationDelegate = (TouchTrackerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

-(void)endTouches:(NSSet *)touches
{
if([EditModeSingleton isEditMode]){
for(UITouch *t in touches){
    NSValue *key = [NSValue valueWithPointer:t];
    Line *line = [linesInProcess objectForKey:key];

    if(line){
        [completeLines addObject:line];
        [linesInProcess removeObjectForKey:key];
        [navigationDelegate setCompleteLines:completeLines];
        NSLog(@"completeLines count: %i", [completeLines count]);
    }
}
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}
   else {NSLog(@"in Play mode");}

}
```

The problem arises in my View.m when I call '[navigationDelegate setCompleteLines:completeLines];'.  As far as I can tell, this never executes.  I'm also not sure if my setter method is correct in the way I'm trying to pass the array from my view to the app delegate for use in other classes.  If there is a better way of doing that, I'd appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest setting some breakpoints, step through code and see if the variables are what you expect them to be.

Comment: why don't you declare your property like this `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *completeLines;` in AppDelegate.h and put `@synthesize completeLines;` in AppDelegate.m?

Comment: @yAak: Where would you suggest adding breakpoints?  As far as I can tell from my NSLog statements, as I draw the lines they are added in my view, but the array in my appdelegate never has a count > 0.

Azat: I had at first done it that way, but I defined a custom setter to see if it was ever getting to that point.  I probably will change it back to the synthesized methods assuming I can get it to function properly.

Comment: As a side note, the accessor method `getCompleteLines` breaks the [naming conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1004202-BCIGGFCC). The prefix "get" is reserved for methods that return objects indirectly. It should be simply `completeLines`.

Comment: @turboSwag Where do you initialize `TouchDrawView `'s `completeLines` ivar?

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, and sorry, I didn't think to put that in.  Will edit original post to add that in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not entering that function, there's really only one solid possibility:
`navigationDelegate` is nil. Verify this by logging or asserting it just before sending the message to it in `endTouches` and then figure out why.

Cnage:

```
    [linesInProcess removeObjectForKey:key];
    [navigationDelegate setCompleteLines:completeLines];
```

To:

```
    [linesInProcess removeObjectForKey:key];
    NSAssert(navigationDelegate != nil, @"navigationDelegate is nil");
    [navigationDelegate setCompleteLines:completeLines];
```

Comment: I did that and it gave me this:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'navigationDelegate is nil'

So how would I rectify this situation?

Comment: `navigationDelegate` is initialized in a method suspiciously named `viewDidLoad` but `TouchDrawView` is a `UIView` and not a `UIViewController` so that method is not getting called

Comment: Yes, @albertamg is correct. (Good catch.) Set the delegate in `awakeFromNib` instead. And don't forget to call the super. (Actually, doing it in both initWithCoder and initWithFrame might be better. I can't find any documentation on `awakeFromNib`.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it all resolved now and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference/help (and to answer your question in comments) -

**Breakpoint basics in brief:**

- Set breakpoints at or before the line where you suspect your code breaks/fails/behaves-unexpectedly. Run your program in debug...
- If the breakpoint gets hit: Examine both the call-stack and variable-values in the various Debugging panes in Xcode for clues.
- Or if the breakpoint is never hit: Go back up a step in your function calls and set a breakpoint there.

If nothing else, breakpoints can narrow your issue down by process of elimination and help you ask better questions that get answered faster. =)

---

Although StackOverflow helped you track down this problem pretty fast, you can save yourself a lot of time and frustration in the future if you make use of breakpoints.

In this case, setting a breakpoint at or before the line: `[navigationDelegate setCompleteLines:completeLines];` would have revealed `navigationDelegate` was nil. Then you repeat: set a breakpoint at or before `navigationDelegate` is assigned and re-run it. When this breakpoint *didn't* get hit, you would then realize your problem is something other than your setter! =)

You might still have had to ask "why isn't viewDidLoad being called?" but with part of the confusion already solved by you, your answer would have arrived much faster! Hope that helps you in the future~

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for future reference.  Thanks for all of your help!